# Understanding Gaussian Mixture Models

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to understand the results from the scikit-learn gaussian mixture model implementation. Take a look at the following example:

```
#!/opt/local/bin/python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture

# Define simple gaussian
def gauss_function(x, amp, x0, sigma):
    return amp * np.exp(-(x - x0) ** 2. / (2. * sigma ** 2.))

# Generate sample from three gaussian distributions
samples = np.random.normal(-0.5, 0.2, 2000)
samples = np.append(samples, np.random.normal(-0.1, 0.07, 5000))
samples = np.append(samples, np.random.normal(0.2, 0.13, 10000))

# Fit GMM
gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=3, covariance_type="full", tol=0.001)
gmm = gmm.fit(X=np.expand_dims(samples, 1))

# Evaluate GMM
gmm_x = np.linspace(-2, 1.5, 5000)
gmm_y = np.exp(gmm.score_samples(gmm_x.reshape(-1, 1)))

# Construct function manually as sum of gaussians
gmm_y_sum = np.full_like(gmm_x, fill_value=0, dtype=np.float32)
for m, c, w in zip(gmm.means_.ravel(), gmm.covariances_.ravel(), 
               gmm.weights_.ravel()):
    gmm_y_sum += gauss_function(x=gmm_x, amp=w, x0=m, sigma=np.sqrt(c))

# Normalize so that integral is 1    
gmm_y_sum /= np.trapz(gmm_y_sum, gmm_x)

# Make regular histogram
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=[8, 5])
ax.hist(samples, bins=50, normed=True, alpha=0.5, color="#0070FF")
ax.plot(gmm_x, gmm_y, color="crimson", lw=4, label="GMM")
ax.plot(gmm_x, gmm_y_sum, color="black", lw=4, label="Gauss_sum")

# Annotate diagram
ax.set_ylabel("Probability density")
ax.set_xlabel("Arbitrary units")

# Draw legend
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Resulting plot from the code above]

Here I first generate a sample distribution constructed from gaussians, then fit a gaussian mixture model to these data. Next, I want to calculate the probability for some given input. Conveniently, the scikit implementation offer the `score_samples` method to do just that. Now I am trying to understand these results. I always thought, that I can just take the parameters of the gaussians from the GMM fit and construct the very same distribution by summing over them and then normalising the integral to 1. However, as you can see in the plot, the samples drawn from the `score_samples` method fit perfectly (red line) to the original data (blue histogram), the manually constructed distribution (black line) does not. I would like to understand where my thinking went wrong and why I can't construct the distribution myself by summing the gaussians as given by the GMM fit!?! Thanks a lot for any input!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just in case anyone in the future is wondering about the same thing: One has to normalise the individual components, not the sum:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture

# Define simple gaussian
def gauss_function(x, amp, x0, sigma):
    return amp * np.exp(-(x - x0) ** 2. / (2. * sigma ** 2.))

# Generate sample from three gaussian distributions
samples = np.random.normal(-0.5, 0.2, 2000)
samples = np.append(samples, np.random.normal(-0.1, 0.07, 5000))
samples = np.append(samples, np.random.normal(0.2, 0.13, 10000))

# Fit GMM
gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=3, covariance_type="full", tol=0.001)
gmm = gmm.fit(X=np.expand_dims(samples, 1))

# Evaluate GMM
gmm_x = np.linspace(-2, 1.5, 5000)
gmm_y = np.exp(gmm.score_samples(gmm_x.reshape(-1, 1)))

# Construct function manually as sum of gaussians
gmm_y_sum = np.full_like(gmm_x, fill_value=0, dtype=np.float32)
for m, c, w in zip(gmm.means_.ravel(), gmm.covariances_.ravel(), gmm.weights_.ravel()):
    gauss = gauss_function(x=gmm_x, amp=1, x0=m, sigma=np.sqrt(c))
    gmm_y_sum += gauss / np.trapz(gauss, gmm_x) * w

# Make regular histogram
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=[8, 5])
ax.hist(samples, bins=50, normed=True, alpha=0.5, color="#0070FF")
ax.plot(gmm_x, gmm_y, color="crimson", lw=4, label="GMM")
ax.plot(gmm_x, gmm_y_sum, color="black", lw=4, label="Gauss_sum", linestyle="dashed")

# Annotate diagram
ax.set_ylabel("Probability density")
ax.set_xlabel("Arbitrary units")

# Make legend
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer

Comment: This is really succinct, thank you. I was having a lot of trouble passing data into `GaussianMixture.fit` as I didn't realise the shape needed to be `np.expand_dims(samples, 1).shape` instead of `samples.shape`

Comment: Now how would you go about calculating the probability of a new test sample X (so you can estimate whether or not it's likely that the data point is a novelty)? From what I understood, np.exp(gmm.score_samples(X)) gives the value of the PDF at X, not the probability of X.