# Why doesn't the `normed` parameter for matplotlib histograms do anything?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm confused by the `normed` argument from [matplotlib.pyplot.hist](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=matplotlib%20pyplot%20hist#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) and why it does not change the plot output:

> If True, the first element of the return tuple will be the counts
>   normalized to form a probability density, i.e., `n/(len(x)'dbin)`, i.e.,
>   the **integral of the histogram will sum to 1**. If `stacked` is also True,
>   the sum of the histograms is normalized to 1.
>
> Default is False

Seems pretty clear.  I've seen it called a density function, probability density, etc.

That is, given a random uniform distribution of size 1000 in [0, 10]:

[image]

Specifying `normed=True` should change the y-axis to a density axis, where the sum of the bars is 1.0:

[image]

But in reality it does nothing of the sort:

```
r = np.random.uniform(size=1000)
plt.hist(r, normed=True)
```

[image]

And furthermore:

```
print(plt.hist(r, normed=True)[0].sum())
# definitely not 1.0
10.012123595
```

So, I have seen @Carsten König's [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16399741/7954504) to similar questions and am not asking for a workaround.  My question is, what then is the purpose of `normed`?  Am I misinterpreting what this parameter actually does?

The matplotlib [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_percent_demo.html) even gives an example named "histogram_percent_demo", where the integral looks like it would be over a thousand percent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The height of the bars do not necessarily sum to one. 
It is the area under the curve, which is the same as the integral of the histogram, which equals one:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
r = np.random.uniform(size=1000)
hist, bins, patches = plt.hist(r, normed=True)

print((hist * np.diff(bins)).sum())
# 1.0
```

`norm=True` thus returns a histogram which can be interpreted as a probability distribution.

Comment: I don't think it is unintuitive. As [wikipeadia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) also states: "The total area of a histogram used for probability density is always normalized to 1. If the length of the intervals on the x-axis are all 1, then a histogram is identical to a relative frequency plot." So you were expecting a relative frequency plot, but with `norm=True` it really is a probability density plot.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45805316/gaussian-mixture-models-of-an-images-histogram) is a pretty typical example where `normed=True` is useful -- comparing a histogram to a fitted probability distribution. Norming the histogram allows to two to be shown on the same scale

Answer (score 2):

1. According to matplotlib version 3.0.2,

   > `normed` : bool, optional
   >          Deprecated; use the density keyword argument instead.
2. So if you want density plot, use `density=True` instead.
3. Or you can use `seaborn.displot`, which plots histogram by default using density rather than frequency.
4. What  `normed =True` does is to scale area under the curve to be 1, as @unutbu has shown.
5. `density=True` keeps the same property (area under curve sums to 1) and is more meaningful and useful.

   ```
   r = np.random.uniform(size=1000)
   hist, bins, patches = plt.hist(r, density=True)
   print((hist * np.diff(bins)).sum())
   ```

   [Out] 1